# How to list the owner's files that the current user belongs to

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to get the CompanyName of the current user so for that i used two classes like below

```
 public class User
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }

}
 public class Company
{
     public int CompanyID { get; set; }
     public string CompanyName { get; set; }
     public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; } 

}
```

and after that i have to access to shared folder that is contain subdirectories with the company's names and list its files. 
Does anybody have an idea how to do it. 
Thanks

```
   String filePath = Path.Combine(basePath, CompanyName);
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(filePath);
if (dir.Exists)
{
foreach(FileInfo file in dir.GetFiles("*.xml")
{
    String fileName  = dir.Name;

}
```

}

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I m trying to get list of files located in shared directory, this directory contains subdirectories with th company's name so from the current user i have to determine the company name and list his files

Comment: I don't see anything related to directories in that code.

Comment: @CodeCaster this is the part related to directories

Comment: Your problem is unclear. With what part specifically do you have a problem?

Comment: @CodeCaster  the first problem how can i determine the company name from the current user (who logged in ) and the second one is how to pass it(company name) in parameter to get its files (files located under subdirectory with the company's name in shared directory) any way thanks for your patience

Comment: `loggedInUser.Company.CompanyName`?